# Breaking cyclic references with std::weak_ptr and alias constructor: sound or problematic?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, cyclic-reference

I have not yet found the following way of breaking cyclic references explained on any major C++ forum/blog, like on GotW, so I wanted to ask whether the technique is known, and what are its pro and cons?

```
class Node : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {
public:
   std::shared_ptr<Node> getParent() {
      return parent.lock();    
   }

   // the getter functions ensure that "parent" always stays alive!
   std::shared_ptr<Node> getLeft() {
       return std::shared_ptr<Node>(shared_from_this(), left.get());
   }

   std::shared_ptr<Node> getRight() {
       return std::shared_ptr<Node>(shared_from_this(), right.get());
   }

   // add children.. never let them out except by the getter functions!
public:
   std::shared_ptr<Node> getOrCreateLeft() {
       if(auto p = getLeft())
          return p;
       left = std::make_shared<Node>();
       left->parent = shared_from_this();
       return getLeft();
   }

   std::shared_ptr<Node> getOrCreateRight() {
       if(auto p = getRight())
          return p;
       right = std::make_shared<Node>();
       right->parent = shared_from_this();
       return getRight();
   }

private:
   std::weak_ptr<Node> parent;
   std::shared_ptr<Node> left;
   std::shared_ptr<Node> right;
};
```

From the outside, the user of `Node` will not notice the trick with using the aliasing constructor in `getLeft` and `getRight`, but still the user can be sure that `getParent` always returns a non-empty shared pointer, because all pointers returned by `p->get{Left,Right}` keep the object `*p` alive for the lifetime of the returned child pointer.

Am I overlooking something here, or is this an obvious way to break cyclic references that has been documented already?

```
int main() {
   auto n = std::make_shared<Node>();
   auto c = n->getOrCreateLeft();
   // c->getParent will always return non-null even if n is reset()!
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that ultimately *all children* will share the same reference count as the root? That is, if I create `left_A` with the aliasing constructor, then it's reference count is the same as `parent`. Then if I create a new `left_B` off `left_A`, and use `left_A->shared_from_this` - is the reference count still `parent`, as in the indirection continues up the tree? In that case all nodes share the same reference count, and you can never remove a node and recycle its resources until the entire tree is removed?

Comment: @SteveLorimer they do not share the root's reference count unless they have been given to the outside world by one of the `get` functions of a node (which in turn would have been given by another node .. and so on, starting from the root). So unless someone has a reference to a child node, (which perhaps only is the case temporarily when walking the treeor during an asynchronous operation), the reference count is not shared, and resources can be freed.

Comment: I proposed a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056443/196429) that might be relevant in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shared_ptr<Node>` returned by your `getParent` owns the parent, not the parent's parent.

Thus, calling `getParent` again on that `shared_ptr` can return an empty (and null) `shared_ptr`. For example:

```
int main() {
   auto gp = std::make_shared<Node>();
   auto p = gp->getOrCreateLeft();
   auto c = p->getOrCreateLeft();
   gp.reset();
   p.reset(); // grandparent is dead at this point
   assert(c->getParent());
   assert(!c->getParent()->getParent());
}
```

(The inherited `shared_from_this` also passes out `shared_ptr`s that owns the node rather than its parent, but I suppose you can make it harder to mess up by a private using declaration and ban it by contract.)

Comment: I think it works if you store a weak pointer to both the parent and the root and in the get functions pass the root pointer to the alias constructor, right?

Comment: As long as you don't want to support clearing child nodes again. That would result in desaster