# Resolving smart pointer circular references without using weak pointers

Tags: c++, design-patterns, garbage-collection, smart-pointers, circular-reference

Suppose we have a design where a collection of objects have a possibly reciprocating dependency on other objects within the collection:

```
struct Object
{
  ...
  virtual void method();
private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> siblings;
};
```

Circular references are allowed to occur (and do not represent degenerate cases). Normally, circular references would be resolved by weak pointers, but this requires a hierarchical concept of ownership, which doesn't apply in the scenario where all objects are equal peers.

How do we fix the problem of circular references without using weak pointers? Is there a design pattern for this and/or are there specialised garbage collection libraries that could be applied? ("Specialised" in the sense of not being conservative garbage collectors that scan the entire memory space for roots, such as the Boehm GC, but rather, provide an API that limits the scope of operation to just the objects of interest and provides the means of explicitly annotating/enumerating roots in the managed objects.)

Of course, I respect that the ideal solution is to avoid designs where mutual dependencies occur, but for the purposes of the current question, please work with the constraint that a mutual dependency design cannot be avoided. By way of motivating example, consider a recurrent neural network where each neuron is represented as an object that explicitly stores references to its connected neurons.

I've tagged the question `C++`, but language-agnostic answers are also welcomed.

Comment: The design of `weak_ptr` prevents an object from being deleted while in use, because you must convert the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` while you are accessing it.

Comment: Ah, no, I meant that an object can be deleted while one or more other objects refer to it with weak pointers, i.e., while these objects are "using" it. I confer I'm probably misusing "use" in this context; editing to correct...

Comment: "_Normally, circular references would be resolved by weak pointers_" As a rule: no. **Weak references are absolutely not designed to break cycles.** Just disregard the advice of anyone who tells you that crap. Any ownership cycle can only be "broken" by a different design w/o that problematic cycle. But you can make designs w/o an ownership cycle because you have weak references that are non owning by definition. It's always a design issue. If you have ownership cycle, you can't have smart ptr semantics: by definition they can't possibly handle cycle, not even in theory.

Comment: Agreed: smart pointers do not work with circular references (hence asking the question), but what _does_? Circular references certainly have a valid place in some designs and are handled without drama in garbage collected languages, so what do we do in languages without a GC? Certainly, reinventing an application-specific, ad-hoc garbage collector is not a solution, and neither is considering circular references a design deficiency: for some problems, they are elegant and natural solutions. So, agree that smart pointers aren't the solution, but what _is_?

Answer (score 1):

In certain circumstances where we can manage `Object` instances as a group, the aliasing constructor of `std::shared_ptr` provides a partial solution to the problem. I don't consider this a proper solution, but I'm posting it in hope of spurring further discussion. Instead of using a completely generic formularisation, I'll describe the solution in the context of the proposed use-case of an artificial neural network.

### Problem

We have a `Neuron` class where each instance references other neurons in a possibly reciprocating relationship (i.e., circular references are expected to occur).

```
struct Neuron {
  std::shared_ptr<Neuron> inputs, outputs;
};
```

We want automatic memory management of `Neuron` instances so that for as long as we hold a smart pointer to a `Neuron`, we can be sure that all its dependencies remain active (i.e., not expired).

### Partial Solution

It's natural to group neurons into networks, and so we can introduce a `Network` class, which is a container that manages and owns a collection of `Neuron` instances:

```
class Network : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Network> {
  std::vector<Neuron> neurons;

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<Network> createNetwork();
  std::shared_ptr<Neuron> getNeuron(size_t indx);
};
```

The API allows the client to get individual `Neuron` instances as shared pointers. While the client holds such a pointer, it should not matter if the `Network` itself has gone out of scope; all dependencies of the referenced `Neuron` should still remain active:

```
std::shared_ptr<Neuron> neuron;
{
  auto network = Network::createNetwork();
  neuron = network.getNeuron(0);
}
neuron.inputs[0]; // <-- alive and well despite the
                  //     {network} smart pointer 
                  //     having been destructed.
```

For this, we can use the aliasing constructor of `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Neuron> Network::getNeuron(size_t const indx) {
  return std::shared_ptr<Neuron>(shared_from_this(), &neurons[indx]);
}
```

### Analysis

The above solution gives us the following:

- Clients get normal `std::shared_ptr` semantics for individually held `Neuron` instances.
- Clients do not need to worry about what happens when their `Network` container goes out of scope.
- Circular references within `Neuron` instances are allowed and do not interfere with memory management.

However, it has the following limitations, which makes it at best a partial solution, and possibly not a solution at all:

- Requires management to be performed by some container class with ownership semantics.
- Does not support multiple containers co-owning objects (i.e., a `Neuron` can only belong to a single `Network`).

Still very much looking for better answers, but in the mean time, hope this might be of curiosity to some passing soul.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a member of each type that releases whatever references are held.

```
struct type1
{
  std::shared_ptr<struct type2> ptr;
  void reset() { ptr.reset(); }
};
struct type2
{
  std::shared_ptr<type1> ptr;
  type2(std::shared_ptr<type1> & ptr) : ptr{ptr} {}
  void reset() { ptr.reset(); }
};
```

It can't be automatic like proper RAII (in that an additional step is needed and not just relying on destructors) but so long as you follow the contract it will keep the object(s) alive so long as they need to be then release them afterward. Depending on exact usage it may also be necessary to move to two-stage initialization (that is, for example with a type1 object, create the object, assign it to a shared_ptr and only then create the type2 object).

Although if that is your pattern you can also very often move to simply having type2 store a raw pointer and not have it worry about the owning object's lifetime at all. With circular chains like this *somewhere* there has to be an external reference and that is the proper place to start unwinding.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So when our `Object` type only has a single possibly-reciprocating dependency, we can create a proxy type that is essentially a pair holding shared pointers to the object and its dependency, thereby ensuring that so long as this proxy never gets destroyed, the Object's dependency will never expire (we can use RAII for this). However, so far as I can work out, this type of solution doesn't work for when objects have a variable number of dependencies. Is this consistent with your thinking?

Comment: Actually, no. . shared_ptr has a rather odd alias ability that allows you to have say a shared_ptr<void> that actually manipulates the lifetime of a shared_ptr<type1>. So you could then have a vector<shared_ptr<void>> of such alias instances. Note that this would not help you with the problem of getting actual objects (the type1*) but _would_ allow you to collect references to all the objects you want to keep alive in one place.

Comment: I can certainly imagine creating a bin where we aggregate shared pointers so that their respective objects don't go out of scope, but I can't imagine how we can do so in such a way that preserves automatic RAII-style memory management. So far as I can see, we would need to periodically traverse our object network to see which objects are still reachable, i.e., rolling our own garbage collector.